# Install specific react-bootstrap component class only?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to building websites with react bootstrap and very recently I used node to install the react-tabs component. I would like to do the same for react-bootstrap/Carousel without installing other react-bootstrap classes and components (as I don't want the css to interfere with existing css in my project as I am using many similar classes as the react-bootstrap library). Please guide me on how to do this. thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a way to do this. I want to do the same thing but can't see anywhere in the docs or on here how I can do it